# Dummy Soundcard for Amazon linux server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to use an application which needs a soundcard in an amazon ec2 instance with the default ubuntu 16.04 installed on it. Problem is that there's no soundcard available. I've tried everything on google on how to create a dummy soundcard so the program runs with no problem, but nothing helped because it was outdated. This is what `lspci`returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446
00:03.0 Unassigned class [ff80]: XenSource, Inc. Xen Platform Device (rev 01)
```

lsmod | grep snd does not return ANYTHING which makes me think that I might me missing all modules, and not just `snd-dummy`.

I've been trying to setup a dummy by using the command `sudo modprobe snd-dummy` which returns the following error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-dummy not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-1013-aws
```

Any clues?

Comment: have you tried this already? https://superuser.com/questions/344760/how-to-create-a-dummy-sound-card-device-in-linux-server

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! unfortunately yes, I've tried it. The problem is that when I execute modprobe, it doesnt find the dummy module :(

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still has the same issue:

You are probably using an AMI that comes with a kernel compiled without the `snd-dummy` module. The [ALSA wiki](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-dummy) suggests building this module from source (`alsa-driver`) but this is out of date.

I was able to run an application that needs a soundcard on EC2 by installing pulseaudio

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
pulseaudio --start
```

After which I get:

```
$ aplay test.wav 
Playing WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 22257 Hz, Mono
```

And the soundcard-needing application runs normally. If this is not enough for you, you might need to enable the default sink:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=auto_null
pactl set-default-sink auto_null
```

More details here [Linux application fails with "Invalid CTL" and "Unknown PCM"](https://pcatach.github.io/tech/2022/05/31/invalid-ctl-unknown-pcm.html)